# Angular.js routing inside java app

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to enable routing with angular.js in a java application (I've never been a java developer).

This way everything but routing works pretty well:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  //'ngRoute',
  'ngResource',  
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]);
```

All tutorials and books tell me to do something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource',  
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/nodes/:nodeId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/nodeinfo.html',
        controller: 'contentController'
    }).
    otherwhise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

But when I enable routing all the thing I've already done, the partial views stop working. 
Then if I uncomment the .config part, node.js get completely broken and i can see curly braces as simple text. (sorry if I'm not being clear)

I tried different ways:

```
.config(function($provider, $routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/nodes/:nodeId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/nodeinfo.html',
        controller: 'contentController'
    }).
    otherwhise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
})
```

But I have to admit actually I don't know what I'm doing.
Thank you everyone in advance for your help!

Comment: It's a spring application, by the way.

Comment: This is about angular.js, not node.js or java.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really tired. It's angular.js, however I'm still working on the web interface for a jvm app.. I guess.